# In-place Views block field edits

Tags: views, theming, entities, ajax

I have a Views block showing the profile of a user. I would like to make it look like so:

[image]

where there is a button next to some of the changeable fields, when clicked will make the field value a textbox, where the user can update it.

How can I achieve this with Drupal?

Config: Drupal 7, Bartik theme.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to have such functionality working with views generated fields. Solutions that are close to this functionality are available but may not provide acceptable UX.

For Views you can check out [Editable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews) and [Edit Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/edit_views) modules.

You can also try [Quick Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465636/inline-add-edit-delete-data-in-views-in-drupal-7) module, but you will have to give up rendering your fields w/ Views, as it doesn't support fields generated by Views now and not sure if it will.